# HttpClient multithread performance

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an application which downloads more than 4500 html pages from 62 target hosts using `HttpClient (4.1.3 or 4.2-beta)`. It runs on Windows 7 64-bit. Processor - Core i7 2600K. Network bandwidth - 54 Mb/s.

At this moment it uses such parameters:

- `DefaultHttpClient` and `PoolingClientConnectionManager`;
- Also it has`IdleConnectionMonitorThread` from
  `http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html`;
- Maximum total connections = 80;
- Default maximum connections per route = 5;
- For thread management it uses `ForkJoinPool` with the parallelism
  level = 5 (Do I understand correctly that it is a number of working
  threads?)

In this case my network usage (in Windows task manager) does not rise above 2.5%. To download 4500 pages it takes 70 minutes. And in HttpClient logs I have such things:

> DEBUG ForkJoinPool-2-worker-1
>   [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager]: Connection
>   released: [id: 209][route: {}->http://stackoverflow.com][total kept
>   alive: 6; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 10 of 80]

Total allocated connections do not raise above 10-12, in spite of that I've set it up to 80 connections.
If I'll try to rise parallelism level to 20 or 80, network usage remains the same but a lot connection time-outs will be generated.

I've read tutorials on hc.apache.org ([HttpClient Performance Optimization Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html) and [HttpClient Threading Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html)) but they does not help.

Task's code looks like this:

```
public class ContentDownloader extends RecursiveAction {
    private final HttpClient httpClient;
    private final HttpContext context;
    private List<Entry> entries;

    public ContentDownloader(HttpClient httpClient, List<Entry> entries){
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        context = new BasicHttpContext();
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    private void computeDirectly(Entry entry){      
        final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(entry.getLink());
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get, context);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if ( (statusCode >= 400) && (statusCode <= 600) ) {
                logger.error("Couldn't get content from " + get.getURI().toString() + "\n"  + response.toString());
            } else {        
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    String htmlContent = EntityUtils.toString(entity).trim();
                    entry.setHtml(htmlContent);
                    EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(entity);                             
                }
            }                           
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (entries.size() <= 1){           
            computeDirectly(entries.get(0));
            return;         
        }       
        int split = entries.size() / 2;     
        invokeAll(new ContentDownloader(httpClient, entries.subList(0, split)), 
                new ContentDownloader(httpClient, entries.subList(split, entries.size())));
    }
}
```

And the question is - what is the best practice to use multi threaded `HttpClient`, may be there is a some rules for setting up `ConnectionManager` and `HttpClient`? How can I use all of 80 connections and raise network usage?

If necessary, I will provide more code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how many different hosts you are pulling from but if it's a small number (or just 1), you want to increase the max per route. This will increase your concurrency per host.

Currently you have it set to 5. Your're observing a max connection usage of up to 10-12, perhaps you're only hitting 2-3 different hosts, in which case, the math adds up.

Answer (score 1):

The remote site could limit the number of parallel connections from one IP. In fact this is good practice since many crawlers are badly implemented and incur high burden on the servers.

You should at least respect the robots.txt and limit your requests to one per second per remote ip if you crawl a public site and not your own.

In addition to that you have a maximum number of connections per route (that is http://www.example.com/[whatever]) of five, so you can expect to have at most 5 parallel connections to one remote "site". (The path is ignored, just scheme, host and port.)

Answer (score 0):

Apache HttpClient should definitely be fast enough to saturate bandwidth even of loopback interfaces. I suspect that the performance issue has more to do with the efficiency of content processing than that of content retrieval. Your application is simply spending more time processing HTML content and extracting links than downloading new pages thus causing bandwidth under-utilization. Even the fact that your code converts HTML content to String prior to processing it leads me to believe that your application spends more time copying stuff in memory than transferring data across the wire.

Comment: I've removed all content processing but nothing has changed. Can this problem be caused by the same thing as this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673517/setmaxforroute-does-not-work-in-threadsafeclientconnmanager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673517/setmaxforroute-does-not-work-in-threadsafeclientconnmanager)?

Comment: UPD: The CPU load with content processing is about 0-1%.

Comment: @pepper: This makes no sense. If you removed content processing, how on earth does your application extract links for subsequent fetches?

Comment: @papper: in any case I think you would be much better off re-using one of several web crawlers based on HttpClient then trying to implement your own.

Comment: I have a number (about 60) rss feeds and application extracts links from them and provides to `ContentDownloader` throw `List<Entry> entries`. So I don't need to recursively extract links from content. The only need is to download html page. I'm newbie in Java, may be you can advice a web crawler for this task?

Comment: @pepper: Apache Droids (incubating) http://incubator.apache.org/droids/; crawler-commons: http://code.google.com/p/crawler-commons/; Bixo: http://openbixo.org/